# Is there a way to Batch install multiple applications with different installers?installer

Tags: installation, batch

Is there a way I can install all my applications in windows at one time? eg, I want to install microsoft office, then mozilla firefox, then some other apps. I'd like to be asked my preference settings one time, and have the rest done automatically,installing all the application that I had chosen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this: http://www.guidingtech.com/1369/how-to-batch-install-programs-on-your-pc-with-ninite/

Probably doesn't support all software though.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a .bat file and use the [start command](http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm) to install the applications you need. If the setup files are not available via some url then you need to keep them on your hard drive.

Would be a nice setup to create a simple install folder and use relative paths, keeping the .bat file on the root folder

```
@Echo on
start /wait office\setup.exe
start /wait firefox\setup.exe
start /wait someapp\setup.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Try https://chocolatey.org. It is designed as "a Machine Package Manager, somewhat like apt-get, but built with Windows in mind." And let's you both download and install packages in one command.

For instance, to install Notepad++ one simply types

```
choco install notepadplusplus
```

And both the download and install are done by powershell for you. This makes upgrades seamless also because of the package database that it tracks.

This tool is by far the easiest for automating the install of most open-source or free tools such as firefox. However, in an enterprise environment, when setting up multiplemachines it may be useful to use [Windows Deployment Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj648426.aspx), a free role for Windows Server. WDS allows you to complete zero-touch installs from a tftp network boot, through drive partitioning, BitLocker encryption, OS and driver installation, through installation of specific Microsoft software such as Office and joining the computer to a domain.